# Returning mp4 video with Slim 3

Tags: php, laravel, video, mime-types, slim

I wanted to have an endpoint that would return an mp4 video.

The full endpoint was

```
$app->get('{userid}/clips/{clipid}/video', '\GameDVRController:clipGetVideo');
```

And the function for that endpoint is

```
public function clipGetVideo($request, $response, $args) {
    $clipid = $args['clipid'];
    $clip = GameClip::where('id', $clipid)->first();

    // (Note: clip->File is full path to file on disk)
    $file = file_get_contents($clip->File);
    $response->getBody()->write($file);

    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'video/mp4');
    return $response;
}
```

When I go to the endpoint, chrome recognizes that it's a video, but I don't think it's returning any of the actual video.  The player doesn't see anything, and it loads in a split second.

Comment: How big is the file?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably and issue with big files, for me all seems to work with files that are ~20mb big.

I could fix the issue by setting the file as a stream like this:

```
public function clipGetVideo($request, $response, $args) {
    set_time_limit(0);

    $clipid = $args['clipid'];
    $clip = GameClip::where('id', $clipid)->first();

    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'video/mp4');
    return $response->withBody(new Stream(fopen($clip->File, "rb")))
}
```

or by using an not Slim approach with custom buffering:

```
public function clipGetVideo($request, $response, $args) {
    set_time_limit(0);

    $clipid = $args['clipid'];
    $clip = GameClip::where('id', $clipid)->first();

    header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($clip->File));

    $handle = fopen($clip->File, "rb");
    while (!feof($handle)){
        echo fread($handle, 8192);
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
    fclose($handle);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a great solution (see link below), that works great for Slim 4. You just have to create a class as you find below, named VideoStream and call the named methods in your code. On top of the question asked, this code provides a bytewise stream, which is helpful for big video files. Code:

```
        $video_path = 'your_file_path';
        $stream = new VideoStream($video_path);

        return $response->withBody($stream->start());
```

`VideoStream` class - thanks to Rana:

```
<?php
/**
 *  * Description of VideoStream
 *   *
 *    * @author Rana
 *     * @link https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video- 
streaming-tutorial
 *      */
class VideoStream
{
private $path = "";
private $stream = "";
private $buffer = 102400;
private $start  = -1;
private $end    = -1;
private $size   = 0;

function __construct($filePath) 
{
    $this->path = $filePath;
}

/**
 *      * Open stream
 *           */
private function open()
{
    if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
        die('Could not open stream for reading');
    }

}

/**
 *      * Set proper header to serve the video content
 *           */
private function setHeader()
{
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this- 
    >path)) . ' GMT' );
    $this->start = 0;
    $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
    $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

        $c_start = $this->start;
        $c_end = $this->end;

        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this- 
        >size");
            exit;
        }
        if ($range == '-') {
            $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{
            $range = explode('-', $range);
            $c_start = $range[0];

            $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? 
        $range[1] : $c_end;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= 
        $this->size) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this- 
        >size");
            exit;
        }
        $this->start = $c_start;
        $this->end = $c_end;
        $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
        fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Length: ".$length);
        header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this- 
    >size);
    }
    else
    {
        header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
    }  

}

/**
 *      * close curretly opened stream
 *           */
private function end()
{
    fclose($this->stream);
    exit;
}

/**
 *      * perform the streaming of calculated range
 *           */
private function stream()
{
    $i = $this->start;
    set_time_limit(0);
    while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
        $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
        if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
        }
        $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
        echo $data;
        flush();
        $i += $bytesToRead;
    }
}

/**
 *      * Start streaming video content
 *           */
function start()
{
    $this->open();
    $this->setHeader();
    $this->stream();
    $this->end();
}
}
```

[Source](https://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial)

Comment: Please properly attribute this code to its original source by URL or it will be flagged as plagiarism.

Comment: Hi Miken32, thank you for your hint. I added the link in code and at the end of my post.